# swiftプログラムでQRコード作成

Tags: swift, qr-code

swiftプログラムでQRコードの読み取りには
.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
と標準のフレームワークがありますが、QRコード作成の標準フレームワークが見つかりません。

ZXingObjCを使えばできるのですが、もし標準のフレームワークがあるのにZXingObjCを使っていても嫌なので、もしあればご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`CIQRCodeGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator) で:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

func createQRCode(message: String, correctionLevel: String = "M", moduleSize: CGFloat = 1) -> UIImage {

    let dat = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    let qr = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator", withInputParameters: [
        "inputMessage": dat,
        "inputCorrectionLevel": correctionLevel,
        ])!

    // moduleSize でリサイズ
    let sizeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(moduleSize, moduleSize)
    let ciImg = qr.outputImage!.imageByApplyingTransform(sizeTransform)

    return UIImage(CIImage: ciImg, scale: 1, orientation: .Up)
}
```

[image: screenshot]

例では、`CIImage` バックエンドの `UIImage` を生成していますが、使用用途によっては`CGImage` 取れないと不便かもしれないので、その場合最後の`return`文を:

```
    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    let cgImg = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImg, fromRect: ciImg.extent)
    return UIImage(CGImage: cgImg, scale: 1, orientation: .Up)
}
```

にすれば良いかと思います。

Comment: ただ、`CIQRCodeGenerator` だと、Versionを明示的に指定できないので、生成してみるまで画像の大きさが不明っていう不便さはあります。

Answer (score 3):

QRコードの生成には、Core Image frameworkに含まれている、`CIQRCodeGenerator`を使うことができます。

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator